# AChartEngine, X labels are not showed

Tags: android, achartengine

I've code a TimeChart, but X labels are not showed, and i don't know why. That's the code for build View with an empty graph, and method for fill it:

```
GraphicalView graphicalView = null;
TimeSeries series = null;
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = null;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
public View buildGraph() {
    series = new TimeSeries("");
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    // set properties
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setLineWidth(2);


    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multipleRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    multipleRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    multipleRenderer.setPointSize(8);
    multipleRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multipleRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    multipleRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    multipleRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    // create view
    if (graphicalView == null) {
        graphicalView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset,
                multipleRenderer, "");
        graphicalView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = graphicalView
                        .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            " " + dateFormat.format(seriesSelection.getXValue()) + "  "
                                    + seriesSelection.getValue(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return graphicalView;
}

// refresh graph
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void refresh(ArrayList<String[]> list) {

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            series.add(dateFormat.parse(list.get(i)[2]),
                    Double.valueOf(list.get(i)[0]));
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    graphicalView.repaint();
}
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is some logic that makes sure to display nice rounded labels. However, there are cases when you don't want these labels and the best example is the time chart. I suggest you add the following call:

```
multipleRenderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```

Comment: Post a screenshot and some X axis values that you are using.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bxi2arJ2Dv9xZlpTNlVtVTJ6YjQ&usp=sharing

The graph is referred to T values showed in ListView

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but whatever I try, I still get the labels displaying. You are probably doing something wrong outside the code you have posted.

Comment: it's the only part of code for build graph. The rest of my application classes are for other tasks

Comment: what version of AChartEngine and minimum sdk build targer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Although this problem in the past for a long time，i still want to answer it.
Use the AChartEngine library ,i have the some problem:
I want refersh the timeChat view in many times，and i don't want create and remove GraphicalView many times. But when i set the new data for TimeSeries, the x lables are not showed.
I add this code in TimeChart.java:

```
    public void clear() {
    mStartPoint = null;
   }
```

and then when i need refersh,i call like this:

```
    mTimeChart.clear();
    mSeries.add(dates1[i], values[i]);//add new data
    mGraphicalView.repaint();//invalidate
```